# Why using just return in Slim framework cause my app to run forever?

Tags: php, response, slim

The weird issue I've encountered is that when I don't set body or set it to an empty string:

```
$this->app()->response->setBody('');
```

It causes my browser to load forever.

When I use `die();` it works but it turns all headers to their default value. For instance `401` becomes `200`.

`$this->app()->stop();` loads forever too.

It's good to note that when I set body to at least one character it works! (for instance a space):

```
$this->app()->response->setBody(' ');
```

Comment: Set [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/it/function.set-time-limit.php) to a 10/15 and enable display_errors, do you get a fatal error?

Comment: When display_errors is on I just get a warning. which is OK.